# Invalid Geometry when Importing Shapefile into Excel 2016 PowerMaps

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geometry, excel

I downloaded Public_School_Locations from [NYC Open Data website](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Education/School-Point-Locations/jfju-ynrr)

When I attempt to import Public_Schools_Points_2011-2012A.shp into Excel 2016 PowerMaps this is what I get

[image]

When I attempt to pick region name, I get a list[image]

When I pick an entry, then the error message shows, i.e. `invalid geometry`[image]

How do I troubleshoot? I downloaded QGIS and came across a [QGIS Tutorial website](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/), but how do I even begin to resolve this?

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I downloaded the dataset and in QGIS I found 6 topology errors (duplicate geometry);
To load errors: follow http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/it/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html

To correct them, move them manually (there are few)